# Convert JSON structure using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Can any one help me to convert the below `array` of `JSON` using `javascript` or `jquery`

```
[ 
[{"day1":10,"day2":154,"day3":24,"day4":48,"day5":154,"day6":48,"day7":154,"name":"Packet"}],
[{"day1":10,"day2":154,"day3":24,"day4":48,"day5":154,"day6":48,"day7":154,"name":"car"}],
[{"day1":10,"day2":154,"day3":24,"day4":48,"day5":154,"day6":48,"day7":154,"name":"bike"}]
]
```

into

```
[
{"name":"Packet","date":"Day1","value":10},
{"name":"Packet","date":"Day2","value":154},
{"name":"Packet","date":"Day3","value":24},
{"name":"Packet","date":"Day4","value":48},
{"name":"Packet","date":"Day5","value":154},
{"name":"Packet","date":"Day6","value":48},
{"name":"Packet","date":"Day7","value":154},

{"name":"car","date":"Day1","value":10},
{"name":"car","date":"Day2","value":154},
{"name":"car","date":"Day3","value":24},
{"name":"car","date":"Day4","value":48},
{"name":"car","date":"Day5","value":154},
{"name":"car","date":"Day6","value":48},

{"name":"bike","date":"Day1","value":10},
{"name":"bike","date":"Day2","value":154},
{"name":"bike","date":"Day3","value":24},
{"name":"bike","date":"Day4","value":48},
{"name":"bike","date":"Day5","value":154},
{"name":"bike","date":"Day6","value":48},]`
```

please provide any help or any example where I can get some hint....as I am new to `JS`.

Comment: you need to implement your own method in Javascript or Jquery becoz its logical problem, first read array one by one and then implement your own given JSON structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.

```js
var array = [
  [{ "day1": 10,"day2": 154,"day3": 24,"day4": 48,"day5": 154,"day6": 48,"day7": 154,"name": "Packet" }],
  [{ "day1": 10,"day2": 154,"day3": 24,"day4": 48,"day5": 154,"day6": 48,"day7": 154,"name": "car" }],
  [{ "day1": 10,"day2": 154,"day3": 24,"day4": 48,"day5": 154,"day6": 48,"day7": 154,"name": "bike" }]
];

function convert(array) {
  if (!array instanceof Array && array.length === 0) {
    return array;
  }
  
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var item = array[i][0];
    var name = item.name;
    
    for (var key in item) {
      if (key === 'name') {
       continue;
      }
      
      result.push({ "name": name,"date": key,"value": item[key]});
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

var result = convert(array);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var inp = [ 
          [{"day1":10,"day2":154,"day3":24,"day4":48,"day5":154,"day6":48,"day7":154,"name":"Packet"}],
          [{"day1":10,"day2":154,"day3":24,"day4":48,"day5":154,"day6":48,"day7":154,"name":"car"}],
          [{"day1":10,"day2":154,"day3":24,"day4":48,"day5":154,"day6":48,"day7":154,"name":"bike"}]
          ];

var res=[];
inp.map(x=>x.map(y=>{for(z in y) {if (z!='name')  res.push({"name":y.name, "date":z,"value":y[z] });}}));
JSON.stringify(inp);
```